# [AWS Lambda]: How to fix "/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, glibc, libc

I'm attempting to use [gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) in a lambda function utilizing a Node.js 14.x runtime. Executing the function throws the following error:

```
ERROR /opt/gifsicle: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /opt/gifsicle)
```

After doing some due diligence, I believe I need to add a layer to my lambda that contains the directory and required dependency noted in the error - but I'm at a total loss as to how to go about doing so.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). The information on how to create the layer content is rather poor. What you need to do is the following:

- Spawn an EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2
- Install gifsicle into it. You probably need to build it from source.
- Create a zip file. The gifsicle should go to the bin folder and any required libraries to lib folder.

This zip file should be ready to upload as a Lambda layer.

Comment: the error references `lib64/` not `lib/` which is where my confusion lies. I created the zip bundle from my local linux machine that's runs Gifsicle & it runs just fine. I'm just confused as to exactly what lib folder to include in the bundle.

Comment: Your local file probably won't work. You need to compile gifsicle in an EC2 environment. As the error says glibc version 2.29 isn't found. In your system the binary is built against the glibc 2.29, but this isn't available in the Lambda container. I am afraid that there is no shortcut. You need to spawn an EC2 instance, install your binary and create the zip file there.

Comment: I spawed a new EC2 instance, installed Gifsicle, created zip including gifisicle and entire /lib64/* folder - pushed that layer up to lambda via was cli & I am still getting that issue. I need to know how to configure lambda to look into the /lib64 folder of my zip file

Comment: @JohnDurand were you able to fix this issue? I'm facing a similar one